# Multiple selection in edit mode and passing the data elsewhere

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, multipleselection

I have a Tabview with two tabs (My Stories and Favorites). When I enter edit mode in My Stories, I want to be able to select multiple stories to add to Favorites. Code I have, work to a certain extent. I can select multiple stories, but when I press button "Add Favorite", only the last story I selected gets added to Favorites. I can't figure out how to store all the selected stories into Favorites. Here's the relevant code:

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        row = indexPath.row
        if tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.selected == true {

        addToFavorites(row)

        }
    }
    func addToFavorites(row: Int) {
        passedTitle = storyTableViewTitle[row]
        passedText = storyTableViewText[row]
        doneEditingRows()
    }


    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, addNewStoryViewControllerDelegate, editStoryTextDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var storyTableViewTitle = [String]()
    var storyTableViewText = [String]()
    var row = Int()
     func addNewStory() {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showNewStory", sender: self)
    }

    func addToFavorites() {
        passedTitle.append(storyTableViewTitle[row])
        passedText.append(storyTableViewText[row])
        doneEditingRows()
    }

    func editRows() {
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
        if storyTableViewTitle != [] {
        tableView.editing = true
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: self, action: "doneEditingRows")
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add Favorite", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "addToFavorites")
        } else {
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Edit, target: self, action: "editRows")
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.enabled = false
        }

    }
    func doneEditingRows() {

        tableView.editing = false
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Edit, target: self, action: "editRows")
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "addNewStory")
        if storyTableViewTitle == [] {
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.enabled = false
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.editing = false
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Edit, target: self, action: "editRows")
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled = true
        if storyTableViewTitle == [] {
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.enabled = false
        }
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return storyTableViewTitle.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = storyTableViewTitle[indexPath.row]
        cell.accessoryType = .DetailButton

        return cell
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let val = storyTableViewTitle.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
        let val1 = storyTableViewText.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)

        storyTableViewTitle.insert(val, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
        storyTableViewText.insert(val1, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)

    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: self, action: "doneEditingRows")
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled = false
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Destructive, title: "Delete") {(action, indexPath) in

            self.storyTableViewTitle.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            self.storyTableViewText.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

            let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

            defaults.setObject(self.storyTableViewText, forKey: "storyText")
            defaults.setObject(self.storyTableViewTitle, forKey:"storyTitle")
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

            tableView.reloadData()

        }
        let favoriteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Favorite") {(action, indexPath) in
            passedTitle.append(self.storyTableViewTitle[indexPath.row])
            passedText.append(self.storyTableViewText[indexPath.row])
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
        favoriteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        return [deleteAction,favoriteAction]
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        row = indexPath.row
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showStory", sender: self)
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.selected == true {
            row = indexPath.row
        }
    }
    import UIKit

var passedTitle = [String]()
var passedText = [String]()

class FavoritesTableViewController: UITableViewController, editStoryTextDelegate {


    var favoriteTitles = [String]()
    var favoriteTexts = [String]()
    var row = Int()



   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if let storyTextArray = defaults.objectForKey("favoriteStoryText") as? [String] {
        favoriteTexts = storyTextArray
    }
    if let storyTitleArray = defaults.objectForKey("favoriteStoryTitle") as? [String] {
        favoriteTitles = storyTitleArray
    }

    tableView.reloadData()



        navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .Black
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()]

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Edit, target: self, action: "editRows")

    }
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)


        // use for defaults reset

//        favoriteTitles = []
//        favoriteTexts = []
//        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
//        defaults.setObject(favoriteTitles, forKey: "favoriteStoryTitle")
//        defaults.setObject(favoriteTexts, forKey: "favoriteStoryText")

        if passedTitle != [] {
            if passedText != [] {
                favoriteTitles.append(passedTitle[row])
                favoriteTexts.append(passedText[row])
                passedTitle = []
                passedText = []

                let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

                defaults.setObject(self.favoriteTexts, forKey: "favoriteStoryText")
                defaults.setObject(self.favoriteTitles, forKey:"favoriteStoryTitle")
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        if favoriteTitles != [] {
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.enabled = true
        } else {
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.enabled = false
        }

    }
       //MARK: TabelView Delegates

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return favoriteTitles.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("favoritesCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = favoriteTitles[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        row = indexPath.row
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showFavoriteStory", sender: self)
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            favoriteTitles.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            favoriteTexts.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)


            let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

            defaults.setObject(self.favoriteTexts, forKey: "favoriteStoryText")
            defaults.setObject(self.favoriteTitles, forKey:"favoriteStoryTitle")


            tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let val = favoriteTitles.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
        let val1 = favoriteTexts.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)

        favoriteTitles.insert(val, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
        favoriteTexts.insert(val1, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.editing = false
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Edit, target: self, action: "editRows")
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled = true
        if favoriteTitles == [] {
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.enabled = false
        }
    }
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: self, action: "doneEditingRows")

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func addToFavorites(row: Int) {
passedTitle = storyTableViewTitle[row]
passedText = storyTableViewText[row]
doneEditingRows()
}
```

By looking at your above code it seems like `passedTitle` and `passedText` are just normal String variables and hence they only save the last selected row as they can hold only one value.
In order to select multiple value you can change those variable to `Array`

you can declare Array in Swift like this:

```
var passedTitle = [String]() //Empty array of type String
var passedText = [String]()
```

Below function will changed to:

```
func addToFavorites(row: Int) {
    passedTitle.append(storyTableViewTitle[row])
    passedText.append(storyTableViewText[row])
    doneEditingRows()
    }
```

Hence your above array will keep storing values every time you select a row. you can use `for` loop to extract data from an array.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: The reason they were declared as simple Strings is that they are declared elsewhere out of class, so I can access them from other classes, and they would then after being set, append to other array. I did however change them to your suggestion, but that didn't help. I'm still bad with loops and don't know how to implement them properly, and I think that might be the answer. I posted some more code so you get a better picture of what my intentions are.

Comment: Ok, I made it happen, although without any loops. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. For that you deserved my vote :)